# Xcode 11 "'==' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer" error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11

I tried to build my project in Xcode 11 and it throws 26 identical errors

```
<unknown>:0: error: '==' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer
```

The errors happen on `Compile Swift source files stage` upon calling `CompileSwift normal arm64 /long/path/to/MyClass.swift ...`. There is no context help pointing to anything *within* the files. The files are quite different but look harmless and does not share anything in common.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of pain, I found the 4-month old app version compiles fine. So I did `git bisect` and found the offending commit, and then this code:

```
struct Config: Equatable {
    let formatDescription: CMFormatDescription
    let orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation
}
```

Turns out `CMFormatDescription` did become `Equatable` only in iOS 13, while the app deployment target is iOS 11. It probably felt back to `[NSObject isEqual:]` in Xcode 10, but it became complicated in Xcode 11. Since Swift automatically generates `Equatable` conformance under the hood it had troubles in pointing the exact place of the error. The solution is to add your own `Equatable` implementation for `CMFormatDescription`:

```
extension CMFormatDescription: Equatable {
    public static func == (lhs: CMFormatDescription, rhs: CMFormatDescription) -> Bool {
        return CMFormatDescriptionEqual(lhs, otherFormatDescription: rhs)
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe also check out [`CMFormatDescriptionEqual(_:otherFormatDescription:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/1489825-cmformatdescriptionequal) to see if that suits your needs.

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler Thank you, that's a much better solution!